# Lookup unique ID and insert date into next column

Tags: excel, vba

I Have a table that is set out with these headers:

```
Task ID | Description | Date completed | Time completed
```

Let say that the table is set out so that Task ID is in cell A3, Description B3, Date Completed C3, and Time Completed D3. In cell A1 I will input the Task ID to be looked up.

What I would like to happen is that when the macro is run, the Task ID entered into cell A1 is found in the table and then the date and time (at the time of running the Macro) are entered into the corresponding cells in columns C and D.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponding cells"? B1-D1?

Comment: Under the correct header. Date in column C and Time in Column D

Comment: @Tolvic Please close the question by accepting the best answer. It will help future readers of this problem to identify proper solution. Also will add some reputations to ppl who help you. [How to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need a bunch of VLOOKUPS. In cell A1 enter your task ID. In cell A2 enter a VLOOKUP for the description  (Assuming you have 100 Ids)

```
=VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$4:$D$100,2,FALSE)
```

and in A3 for the Date etc

```
=VLOOKUP($A$1,$A$4:$D$100,3,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following two procedures represent one way to do what you are interested in. The first uses the `FIND` function to locate the task ID in your table that matches the contents of cell `A1`; the second runs the first procedure whenever you make an entry in `A1`.

#### Date and time logging code

You will need to paste this code into a standard VBA module in the workbook. A standard code module can be inserted by selecting `Visual Basic` from the `Developer` tab of the ribbon, and then choosing `Insert`, `Module` on the main menu of the VBA code editor.

Note that the procedure assumes that the task table is in `Sheet1` of the workbook. If it is in another sheet, you will need to change the name "Sheet1" in the code to the correct name.

```
  Sub LogTaskCompletion()
      Dim lastRow As Long
      Dim foundCell As Range
      With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  '<-- change sheet name here
          If Not .Range("A1").Value = "" Then
              lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
              'do the search
              Set foundCell = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Find(What:=.Range("A1").Value, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
              If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
                  'a match! post the date and time for the task
                  With foundCell
                      .Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
                      .Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"
                      .Offset(0, 3).Value = TimeValue(Now())
                      .Offset(0, 3).NumberFormat = "hh:mm am/pm"
                  End With
              Else
                  'no match!
                  MsgBox "Cannot find task " & .Range("A1").Value
              End If
              .Range("A1").ClearContents
          End If
      End With
  End Sub
```

#### Macro trigger code

This procedure will run the preceding macro whenever an entry is made in `A1`.

It needs to be installed as code private to the worksheet the task table is in. The easiest way to do this is to right-click on the worksheet's tab, select `View Code`, and then paste the code into the editor pane that pops up.

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then 
          Exit Sub
      End If
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      LogTaskCompletion
      Application.EnableEvents = True
  End Sub
```

After installing the code, save the file as an macro-enabled ("xlsm") workbook.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with combination of `Worksheet_Change` and `Vlookup`. Kindly put this code in sheet code section.

Once the value is entered in `A1` the macro is triggered and if the values is found in the table it gets the corresponding values (description) using Vlookup. Also it enters the current date & time.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        On Error Resume Next
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then


            Dim lastRow As Long, tblRng As Range
            lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If lastRow <= 3 Then lastRow = 3

            Set tblRng = Range("A3:D" & lastRow)
            dt = Application.VLookup(Target, tblRng, 1, 0)

            If Not IsError(dt) Then
                With Target
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(Target, tblRng, 2, 0)
                    .Offset(0, 2).Value = Date
                    .Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                    ' if you want  date from tbl use Application.VLookup(Target, tblRng, 3, 0)
                    .Offset(0, 3).Value = TimeValue(Now())
                    .Offset(0, 3).NumberFormat = "hh:mm am/pm"
                    ' if you want  date from tbl use Application.VLookup(Target, tblRng, 4, 0)
                End With

            Else
                With Target
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = vbNullString
                    .Offset(0, 2).Value = vbNullString
                    .Offset(0, 3).Value = vbNullString
                End With
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

[image]